# Write Object to File "Persons.obj"

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader, filereader, printwriter

Hi there fellow Stackoverflowers. I had a question concerning Java, I'm supposed to put all the Objects p1 - p4 in a file called "personen.obj" and for p1, write all data to "persoon1.obj" etc.

Here's the code i'm working with, it doesn't include the Computer class because I thought that isn't neccessary.

This includes some Strings in Dutch, but every Person has a toString with their data. What's supposed to happen is that all the toStrings are written in those files.

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int huidigJaar = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int aanschafJaarC1 = huidigJaar - 4; // c1 is 4 jaar oud
    int aanschafJaarC2 = huidigJaar - 3; // c2 is 3 jaar oud
    Persoon p1 = new Persoon("Eric", 20000);
    Persoon p2 = new Persoon("Hans", 60000);
    Persoon p3 = new Persoon("Willem-Alexander", 8500000);
    Computer c1 = new Computer("Medion", 2000, aanschafJaarC1, "Super");
    Computer c2 = new Computer("Dell", 1500, aanschafJaarC2, "Home");
    if (p1.koop(c1)) {
        System.out.println("Deze koper bezit nu nog " + p1.getBudget());
    }
    if (p1.koop(c1)) {
        System.out.println("Deze koper bezit nu nog " + p1.getBudget());
    }
    if (p2.koop(c1)) {
        System.out.println("Deze koper bezit nu nog " + p2.getBudget());
    }
    if (p2.koop(c2)) {
        System.out.println("Deze koper bezit nu nog " + p2.getBudget());
    }
    if (p3.koop(new Computer("Dell", 1500, aanschafJaarC2, "Home"))) {
        System.out.println("Deze koper bezit nu nog " + p3.getBudget());
    }
    if (p3.koop(c2)) {
        System.out.println("Deze koper bezit nu nog " + p3.getBudget());
    }
    System.out.println("\n" + p1);
    System.out.println(p2);
    System.out.println(p3);
    if (p1.verkoop(c1, p3)) {
        System.out.println("Deze verkoper bezit nu nog " + p1.getBudget());
    }
    if (p2.verkoop(c1, p3)) {
        System.out.println("Deze verkoper bezit nu nog " + p2.getBudget());
    }
    if (p2.verkoop(c2, p1)) {
        System.out.println("Deze verkoper bezit nu nog " + p2.getBudget());
    }
    System.out.println("\n" + p1);
    System.out.println(p2);
    System.out.println(p3);
}
}
```

Comment: check out ObjectOutputStream: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=57 . you'll find as you're learning java, google is your friend, but you do need to know a number of keywords to google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simply writing a small number of strings to a file, I'd recommend using the class "PrintWriter". It wraps itself around a standard Writer and allows you to write any primitive data type and some Objects to a given "Writer" (In our case a FileWriter).

This isn't the only way to write to a file of course nor is it the best way.

I've quickly written up some code from memory, I haven't tested it but I'm pretty sure it works.

```
/**
 * This method will write an array of strings to the given file.
 * If the append flag is set to true, the new data will be added to the end of the file.
 * 
 * Note:
 *  This is not only nor the best way to write to a file.
 * 
 * @param filename - The path to the file you want to write to.
 * @param data - The Strings you want to write to the file.
 * @param append - Should the new data be added to the end of the file?
 * @return If the write operation succeeded.
 */
public static boolean writeStringsToFile(String filename, String[] data, boolean append) {
    boolean resultFlag = true;

    // The file class represents a file on a disk and provides some useful methods
    File file = new File(filename);
    //PrintWriter is used to write various data types to a given writer.
    PrintWriter printWriter = null;

    try {
        //This method will create an empty file, if there's not already one.
        //Will throw an IOException if it experiences an error creating the file.
        file.createNewFile();

        //A PrintWriter needs some kind of writer to output to, we'll use a FileWriter.
        //FileWriter is used for writing to files.
        //Will throw an IOException if the file doesn't exist (It should exist though)
        printWriter = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file, append));

        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            //Write the strings to the file, each on a new line.
            printWriter.println(data[i]);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        //Uh oh. There was an error writing to the disk!
        e.printStackTrace();

        //We couldn't write to the disk, make sure we return false to let the caller know.
        resultFlag = false;
    } finally {
        //First check that we managed to create a PrintWriter before we try to close it.
        if (printWriter!=null)
            printWriter.close(); //Release the file from use.
    }

    return resultFlag;
}
```

It's also worth being aware of encodings. 
Certain systems can/will write text files in different ways than others, in most small cases it's not an issue but it could be potentially.

I very highly recommend giving some of the oracle tutorials a read:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html

Also make sure to give some other sites a read as most will give a different method to solve the same problem, albeit with different pros and cons.